# React Native __NSOperationInternal crash reports

Tags: react-native, crash

There's been a lot of crash lately about __NSOperationInternal. Details are as follows:

`Thread 2 name:
Thread 2 Crashed:
0   Foundation                      0x0000000185848b88 oq_has_observer + 112 (NSOperation.m:0)
1   Foundation                      0x0000000185788680 +[__NSOperationInternal _observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:changeKind:oldValue:newValue:indexes:context:] + 1776 (NSOperation.m:2219)
2   Foundation                      0x0000000185787f58 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 1532 (NSOperation.m:0)
3   Foundation                      0x000000018584876c __NSOQSchedule_f + 404 (NSOperation.m:2081)
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184710a60 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:507)
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184718e94 _dispatch_continuation_pop$VARIANT$mp + 424 (inline_internal.h:2500)
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001847177cc _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 604 (queue.c:3422)
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018471dcac _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 588 (inline_internal.h:2539)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018471d9fc _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 120 (queue.c:6092)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184a43fac _pthread_wqthread + 1176 (pthread.c:2297)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184a43b08 start_wqthread + 4`

Comment: I use react native in project.

the development environment:

Xcode: 9.4.1
React Native: 0.47.2

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post the code that leads to this crash.